# I am trying to change the input value but its not changing, may i know the reason

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change the input value but its not changing.

Onchange the values are not changing

May i know the the reason

any suggestion?

please refer below snippet

```
// snippets
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const StackOverFlow = () => {
    let rowData = [
      { header: "first" },
      { header: "second" },
      { header: "third" }
    ];
    const [name, setName] = useState({ fn: "test" });
    const [data, setData] = useState(rowData);
    const getOnchange = (e) => {
        console.log('--e--',e.target.value)
       setName({ ...name, fn: e.target.value })
    }
    let updateValue = () => {
      setData([
        ...data,
        {
          header: (
            <input
              type="text"
              value={name.fn}
              onChange={getOnchange}
            />
          )
        }
      ]);
    };
    return (
      <div>
        {data.map(val => (
          <h6>{val.header}</h6>
        ))}
        <button onClick={updateValue}> Click </button>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default StackOverFlow
```

Comment: Don't store JSX in state. State is for storing serializable data, not components.

Answer (score 0):

The value is not changing because once you set a JSX in state `data` it will take the value during you call `setData` and does not change when `getOnChange` is executed,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const StackOverFlow = () => {
  let rowData = [
    { header: "first" },
    { header: "second" },
    { header: "third" }
  ];
  const [name, setName] = useState({ fn: "test" });
  const [data, setData] = useState(rowData);
  const getOnchange = e => {
    console.log("--e--", e.target.value);
    setName({ ...name, fn: e.target.value });
  };
  let updateValue = () => {
    setData([
      ...data,
      {
        header: name.fn
      }
    ]);
    setName({ ...name, fn: e.target.value });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {data.map(val => (
        <h6 key={val.header}>{val.header}</h6>
      ))}
      <input type="text" value={name.fn} onChange={getOnchange} />
      <button onClick={updateValue}> Click </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StackOverFlow;
```

this is an alternate approach on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: how can i achieve these kind of probs